# angularjs - Getting the binding expression from an attribute (not the resolved value)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm making a directive that cross fades between images based on this: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2497-Cross-Fading-Images-With-AngularJS.htm

Instead of watching a particular field, i'd like to watch whatever the image is binding to in ngSrc. So rather than (coffeescript):

```
 $scope.$watch "data.ActiveImage", (newValue, oldValue) ->
```

I'd like to use:

```
 $scope.$watch attributes['ngSrc'], (newValue, oldValue) ->
```

Where the DOM element looks like:

```
<img cross-fade-on-change ng-src="{{data.ActiveImage}}"/>
```

The problem is, the watch expression is resolving to the bound url, rather than the binding expression. How/can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$observe` instead of `$watch`:

```
attrs.$observe 'ngSrc', (value) ->
```

- $observe is used for watching attribute interpolations ($interpolate).
- $watch is used for evaluating expressions against a scope ($parse).

### From the docs:

> #### $observe(key, fn)
>
> Observes an interpolated attribute.
>
> #### $watch(watchExpression, listener, objectEquality)
>
> Registers a listener callback to be executed whenever the watchExpression changes.